# Why doesn't a lambda reset initial value?

Tags: ruby, lambda, local-variables

A ruby tutorial on sitepoint has this:

```
def increase_by(i)
  start = 0
  lambda { start += i }
end

increase = increase_by(3)
increase.call # => 3
increase.call # => 6
```

Why doesn't `start` reset to `0` when I call this method the second time? Shouldn't calling both functions return `3`, considering we have `start = 0` at the beginning of the function?

Comment: `start = 0` is not inside the lambda block. It's called only once when you call `increase_by(3)`, not when the lambda is called.

Comment: Don't we invoke the entire function with .call? and not just the lambda alone?

Comment: No. `call` invokes `increase`, not `increase_by`.

Comment: "Why doesn't `start` reset to `0` when I call this method the second time?" – Yes, when you call `increase_by` a second time, the local variable `start` will be `0`. But you don't. Hint: How often *do* you call `increase_by`? How many calls to `increase_by` are in your code?

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty much obvious that there should be no reference to `0` each time `call` is called on `increase`. If it did, where should such `0` come from?

I guess the local variable is set and is stored in the lambda at the time of creation of the lambda. Otherwise, if you just have a reference to the lambda in the context out of the blue, it would not be evident where its local variables come from.

Thus, `start` is bound to the lambda object `increase`. Since you are calling `call` on this same object, the value of `start` is kept.

Answer (score 1):

```
increase = increase_by(3) # Sets start to 0 then returns the lambda which whill now increment start by 3 on each call
increase.call # => 3 # Calls the lambda which adds 3 to start then returns it
increase.call # => 6 # Same as above
```